# Adding more buttons

Tags: java, android, button

I'm working on a app. Past days i'm trying to get more then one button to work on my page. But i can't figur it out. Can some one help? I'm new to Development :)

Layout (xml)

Activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.rust.rustapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="button1Click"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="button1Click"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:
MainActivty:

```
package com.rust.rustapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            private void button1Click()
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Intro.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId())
                {
                case R.id.button1:
                    button1Click();
                    break;
                }

                }
            });
        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Intro.xml (Button1 is opening this page)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/test"
    >


</LinearLayout>
```

Intro.java

```
package com.rust.rustapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Intro extends Activity{



    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.intro);
        }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rust.rustapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Intro"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The new layout name is: FunPage

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

From the code you pasted for `MainActivity`, it looks like you are mixing two different ways to handle button clicks.

If you can to register the click listener from your layout xml, the method corresponding to the onClick attribute needs to be public and not declared as a method inside your `button1` listener.

An alternative is to listen to click events solely with your Java code. If you do this, then remove the onClick attribute from your layout XML for that button. There are many, many examples out there.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        //TODO -- In your case, start the "Intro" activity
    }
}
```

It might help if you extract that method to start the Intro activity to a method outside of the click listener (i.e., as a method of MainActivity).